# rspec - how to filter examples based on multiple tags all being present?

Tags: mobile, rspec, automation, cross-browser, capybara

I wanted to filter some tests based on multiple tags so that ALL the tags have to exist in order to run the test. So AND not OR

I am trying `rspec --tag crossbrowser --tag mobile` but that seems to be running the examples if *either* tag - `mobile` or `cross_browser` - exists whereas I want it only to run if *both* tags exist.

Example feature I **am** trying to target:

```
RSpec.feature 'Rate form stage one', :cross_browser, :mobile, :desktop do
```

Example features I am trying to **avoid** running when running the above:

```
RSpec.feature 'Rate form stage one', :cross_browser, :desktop do
...
RSpec.feature 'Rate form stage one', :cross_browser do
...
```

So far all attempts seem to run all examples with either tag.

Comment: Looks like here is the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46250073/9269043)

Answer (score 1):

RSpec doesn't support that, if one inclusion tag matches the test will be run.  I believe you can combine inclusion with exclusion tags though - so `--tag crossbrowser --tag ~mobile` should run all tests that have crossbrowser but do not have mobile tags which could be a workaround (not necessarily a great workaround) if you pick your tags carefully