# Running Nested Tags in Rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm trying to architect my tests in such a way so I can run certain context blocks by themselves, but also need to further enforce nested tags in individual it blocks.  Something like this:

```
context 'outer context', :outer_tag do
    it 'inner it', :tag1 do
        expect(1).to eq(1)
    end

    it 'inner it 2', :tag2 do
        expect(2).to eq(2)
    end
end
```

and I want to run something along the lines of:

rspec --tag outer-tag --tag tag1

in the hopes that it will only run tests within the context tagged with :outer-tag that are themselves tagged with :tag1

Is there a way to get this behavior?  Currently this seems to operate as an 'or' when I guess I am looking for it to operate as more of an 'and'.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
RSpec.describe 'Something' do
  context 'outer context', :outer_tag do
    it 'inner one', :tag1, outer_tag: 'tag1' do
      expect(1).to eq(1)
    end

    it 'inner two', :tag2, outer_tag: 'tag2' do
      expect(2).to eq(2)
    end
  end

  context 'another context', :different_tag do
    it 'inner three', :tag2, different_tag: 'tag2' do
      expect(3).to eq(3)
    end
  end
end
```

and then running:

```
rspec example.rb --tag 'outer_tag'
# => Something
#      outer context
#        inner one
#        inner two
rspec example.rb --tag 'outer_tag:tag2'
# => Something
#      outer context
#        inner two
rspec example.rb --tag tag2
# => Something
#      outer context
#        inner two
#      another context
#        inner three
```

This starts to get weird when you need multiple levels though:

```
context 'third context', :final_tag do
  context 'inside third', :inner_third, final_tag: 'inner_third' do
    it 'inner four', :inner_four,  inner_third: 'inner_four', final_tag: 'inner_third:inner_four' do
      expect(4).to eq(4)
    end
  end
end

rspec example.rb --tag 'final_tag:inner_third:inner_four'
rspec example.rb --tag 'inner_third:inner_four'
rspec example.rb --tag inner_four
# All run
# => Something
#      third context
#        inside third
#          inner four
```

Works, but is extremely verbose.

And because of the way rspec handles tags on the command line (hashes), it can lead to some unexpected stuff trying to combine them:

```
rspec example.rb --tag outer_tag --tag ~'outer_tag:tag2'
# Run options: exclude {:outer_tag=>"tag2"}
# => Something
#      outer context
#        inner one
#      another context             # <- nothing in this context was expected to run
#        inner three (FAILED - 1)
```

This way works though:

```
rspec example.rb --tag outer_tag --tag ~tag2
# => Something
#      outer context
#        inner one
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use RSpec' [exclusion filter](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-6/docs/filtering/exclusion-filters) to run all your `:outer_tag` tests, except those having the `:tag1` spec.

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.filter_run :outer_tag
  config.filter_run_excluding :tag1
end
```

Only the tests with `:tag2` is run:

```
> rspec -fd tag_spec.rb
Run options:
  include {:outer_tag=>true}
  exclude {:tag1=>true}

outer context
  inner it 2

Finished in 0.00326 seconds (files took 1.07 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures
```

You can use environment variables so as not to modify your code to just to run a subset of the tests.